# What kind of RAM upgrade can the following motherboard handle?

Tags: memory, motherboard

From SIW:
Manufacturer Intel Corporation
Model D850GB
North bridge Intel i850 Revision A2
South bridge Intel 82801BA (ICH2) Revision A2

What RAM typees does it support and how much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the Intel website:

The Intel® Desktop Board D850GB has four RIMM sockets (two sockets for each channel) and supports the following memory features:
Single- or double-sided RIMM configurations
Maximum of 32 Direct Rambus devices per channel
Total system memory configurations from 128 MB (minimum) to 2 GB (maximum) utilizing 128/144 Mbit or 256/288 Mbit technology PC600 or PC800 compliant RDRAM
Serial Presence Detect (SPD) based configuration for optimal memory operation
Suspend to RAM support
ECC and non-ECC support
When installing memory, note the following:

The four RIMM sockets are grouped into two banks:
Bank 0 (labeled on the board as RIMM1 and RIMM2)
Bank 1 (labeled on the board as RIMM3 and RIMM4)
Bank 0 must be populated first ensuring that the RDRAM installed in RIMM1 and RIMM2 is identical in speed, size, and density. For example, the minimum system configuration would use two 64 MB RIMM modules of PC600 or PC800 RDRAM.
If the desired memory configuration has been achieved by populating Bank 0, then Bank 1 should be filled with two Continuity RIMMs.
If memory is to be installed in Bank 1, the RIMM modules installed in RIMM3 and RIMM4 must be identical in size and density to each other, and match the speed of the RIMM modules in Bank 0. The RIMM modules do not, however, need to match those in Bank 0 in size and density. For example, if Bank 0 has two 128 MB RIMMs of PC800 RDRAM, Bank 1 would require PC800 RDRAM also, however, any other supported RIMM modules such as 64 MB or 192 MB could be used.
If ECC functionality is required, all installed RIMM modules must be ECC-compliant.

http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/d850gb/sb/cs-013246.htm#1

Answer (score 2):

From the [Manual](http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/d850gb/A2608002.pdf):

Memory

- Two Direct-RDRAM banks with two RIMM†s per bank (four RIMM sockets)
- Support for up to 2 GB of system memory using PC600 or PC800 RDRAM

Answer (score -1):

Well it supports 2GB RDRAM

> - Total system memory configurations from 128 MB (minimum) to 2 GB
>     (maximum) utilizing 128/144 Mbit or
>     256/288 Mbit technology PC600 or PC800
>     compliant RDRAM
> - The four RIMM sockets grouped into 2 banks:
>
>   - Bank 0 (labeled on the board as RIMM1 and RIMM2)
>   - Bank 1 (labeled on the board as RIMM3 and RIMM4)

Taken from [Intel](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/d850gb/sb/cs-013246.htm#1)

Comment: DDR RAM != RD RAM.